# Getting Color of your button in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4, uibutton

How would you get the colour of your button in iOS? I set the colour of the button. now in another method id like to get it. Is there a getBackgroundCOlour method? I do not see one. Ive set the color with the following code.

```
[self.skinColourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: is `skinColourButton` a `UIButton` or something else?

Comment: I have tried tint colour. That gives me black background.UIColor * newcolour = [self.skinColourButton tintColor];
    self.view.backgroundColor = newcolour; Although my button is not black but its green.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you’re looking for is `backgroundColor`, as in `[self.skinColourButton backgroundColor]`. In Objective-C, the corresponding method to a `-setWhatever:` is usually `-whatever`.

Comment: So you mean something like this?  UIColor * newcolour = [self.skinColourButton getBackGroundColor];  This doesnt work however?

Comment: No. `UIColor *newColour = [self.skinColourButton backgroundColor]`. No “get”, and the “ground” in “background” is not capitalized.

Comment: @CodeGeek123: true, or simply `self.skinColourButton.bakcgroundColor`